# Join us for a ChiliProject UX Hackathon – June 9th, 2012

Tags: discussion, community

Signup sheet is here!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEs3RE9rTU9qZW1ydE5DZzhoUHpyM2c6MQ

[ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/) is an open source issue tracking software. It is a fork of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), an extremely popular and well-made tracking application. I know some of us use it at least one of these in our professional lives, and I think it would be great to give back to ChiliProject by hosting a one-day hackathon focused on UX/UI improvements.

Why ChiliProject over Redmine? ChiliProject's team is more active and takes more contributions from the community, making any work we do more likely to be integrated into a future release. I've spoken about the idea with one of the project leads, and they are definitely open to it.

This gives us as enthusiasts and professionals an opportunity to give back to the open source community.

**What will we be trying to solve?**

ChiliProject definitely improves on Redmine's UX, but it is still lacking in a few key areas, particularly in the UI. Specifically:

1. Main bar navigation could be streamlined
2. Secondary navigation is very busy
3. Typography could benefit from an overhaul
4. Many key processes need to be evaluated and streamlined, including the new issue process. For most of these, the functionality is there, but the usability needs some help.

Some secondary objectives on the UI side might possibly be to port to Twitter Bootstrap, Skeleton, or some other responsive framework to make the site viewport friendly. This is an ambitious task, though.

Of course, through the process of examining the UX, more objectives will be realized.

**When would we do it?**

**Saturday June 9th, 2012**. I will be able to organize a git server and VM for collaborative use, along with a central location for communication. I'll keep this question updated as I gauge interest and get everything together.

Comment: I'll try and drop in if at all possible. Not sure how much help I could be though.

Comment: @ChrisF pre-design analysis is going to be a big need, I think.

Comment: Is there a site that people interested in helping, but unfamiliar with ChiliProject, can look at to see how the product works currently? I'm mildly familiar with RedMine (posted a few bugs for random software I use), but that's about it. I know nothing of the back end either.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys I'd love to get your feedback on this. I'm planning to solve that issue by providing an open source appliance that anyone can download and run to get a working version of CP with the full codebase. Besides that, the source is also available on GitHub.  Can you think of anything else that may be helpful to  anyone that might be interested in participating?

Comment: Preferable to an appliance would simply be a copy of the application (even self hosted on a good speed home line) that all the participants are given administrative access to. It's a web application; local hosting for a dozen people is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Did you ever post on Graphic Design's meta?

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw my hat into the ring

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't there more of these? Yes please. I'm interested.

Comment: Signup sheet is now in the original question.

Comment: If this is a success, it's something we as a community can do more often if we choose. The community bulletin makes these a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I am certainly interested. How do we touchbase ?

Comment: Signup sheet is now in the original question.

Comment: Signed up........ :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds awesome. I'd love to help out.

Comment: Signup sheet is now in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea, I've used Redmine for a few years now.  Definitely interested in helping!

Comment: Signup sheet is now in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely be interested in helping out as well.

Comment: Signup sheet is now in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in - been wanting to contribute to the UX of an open-source project, but wondering where to start. An online place to plan and discuss leading up to the date would be great.  We may have a few people from our local UX meetup (albanyux.org) who would be interested in gathering locally to work together on that day for tasks that may benefit from co-located collaboration... once it's a definite "go" for the date I can publicize.

Comment: Hey Luke! We'd love to have your Meetup participate. I've cemented the date so we should be good to go. We'll be using Google Docs for collaboration - invitations will be going out soon.

Comment: Hey Nick, I'd suggest we use Trello.com for collaboration/communication - it's created by Joel Spolsky (You know, the StackExchange guy)
It's blown my mind lately - perfect for running Lean with built in conversation (and Free)
Here's an overview http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaDf1RqeLfo  It would be great to get the conversation going ASAP. We could back up the collaboration with Google Docs where we need spreadsheets, docs, etc.